# How i upload multiple image's and get it in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel

How i upload multiple image's and get it in view with laravel 5.3 ?

My Controller function is:

```
public function newOffer(Request $request){
    $validate_marge['img'] = 'required|image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg';
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validate_marge);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }else{
        $post = new Post();
        if (Input::hasFile('img')){
            $file = Input::file('img');
            $file->move(public_path('img/offers').'/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
            $post->img = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        }
    }
    $post->title = Input::get('title');
    $post->category_id = Input::get('category_id');
    $post->second_title = Input::get('second_title');
    $post->description = Input::get('description');
    $post->location = Input::get('location');
    $post->price = Input::get('price');
    $post->save();
    return back();
}
```

and is HTML form is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('newOffer') }}"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }} <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Select IMG's</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image"
               name="images[]"
               required
               data-validation-required-message="Please choose image" multiple>
        <p class="help-block">{{$errors->first('images')}}</p>
    </div>
</div> <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%"></form>
```

what i do in Controller to do it and how i preview in post??
Thank You all

Comment: When you upload multiple images, does this function get called for each image upload ?

Comment: Can you please add your form attributes?

Comment: you can add foreach when you are saving your images , but i have a question , does each post has the same image?

Comment: @wahdan done, top in post.

Comment: @HimanshuSharma i need edit this function to upload multiple imgs !

Comment: maybe yes and maybe no, i want save all img in one folder to skip this problem @wahdan

Comment: @MohämmädHämdy check my answer please

Comment: @wahdan not working, no added requests in DB or public path !

Comment: weird , can you add this line `dd(Input::hasFile('img'))` before this line `$post = new Post();` and show the result?

Comment: @wahdan no think happen ! just return back with "The img must be an image." i try now to delete $validate_marge line and see what happen

Comment: @wahdan i'm start function from "$post = new Post();" and delete all lines before, post add to DB, but in img in DB added one image only, and on public path added two image's !

Comment: @MohämmädHämdy check my updated answer

Comment: @wahdan Also return withErrors "The img must be an image".

Comment: @MohämmädHämdy Are you sure you are uploading an image with these types? png,jpg,jpeg?

Comment: @wahdan yes, i sure

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 if (Input::hasFile('img')){
        $file = Input::file('img');
        $file->move(public_path('img/offers').'/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $post->img = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }
```

to

```
        if (Input::hasFile('img')){
                $files = Input::file('img');
                foreach ($files as $file){
                $file->move(public_path('img/offers').'/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
                }
                    $post->img = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $post->title = Input::get('title');
                    $post->category_id = Input::get('category_id');
                    $post->second_title = Input::get('second_title');
                    $post->description = Input::get('description');
                    $post->location = Input::get('location');
                    $post->price = Input::get('price');
                    $post->save();

            }
 return back();
```

you just need to loop through your uploaded files